# Почему не переключается песня WMPLib?

Tags: c#, mediaplayer

Функция, когда заканчивается песня (Сase 8 ' MediaEnded из MSDN), запускает следующую песню, но почему-то когда проигрывает песня, песня меняется, но не проигрывается.

```
private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
    {
        if (NewState == 8 && isRepeat)
        {
            Player.controls.stop();
            if (CurrentMediaIndex + 1 == Playlist.Count)
            {
                CurrentMediaIndex = 0;
                Player.currentMedia = Playlist.First();
            }
            else
            {
                CurrentMediaIndex++;
                Player.currentMedia = Playlist[CurrentMediaIndex];
            }
            Player.controls.play();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ и решение (первоисточник уже не найду).
WMP нужно время, чтобы сменить аудио, поэтому проблему можно решить так:

1. Создаём таймер
       `private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
   {
       if (NewState == 8 && isRepeat)
       {
           Player.controls.stop();
           if (CurrentMediaIndex + 1 == Playlist.Count)
           {
               CurrentMediaIndex = 0;
               Player.currentMedia = Playlist.First();
           }
           else
           {
               CurrentMediaIndex++;
               Player.currentMedia = Playlist[CurrentMediaIndex];
           }
           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new 
           System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
           dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
           dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 10);
           dispatcherTimer.Start();
       }
   }`
2. Создаём событие:
   `private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           if(Player.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsReady)
           {
               Player.control.play();
               (sender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer).Stop();
           }
       }`